# Type error in declaration part in typescript (Angular/React)

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

When i tried run the below component it showing type issue in my declartion

Below is the issue what i am getting
Type '{ First: string[]; Second: string[]; Third: string[]; Four: string[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740

Interface headers declartion
 I have tried the headers data any,String,Array but it was not working

```
   interface headers { 
    First: any[], 
    Second: any[],  
    Third: any[], 
    Four:any[],   
}
```

const headers data declartion

```
const headers = {
      First: [
        'lara',
         'dravid',
         'sachin',
        'Ganguly',
      ],
      Second: [
       'kohli',
         'dhoni',
         'smith',
        'kane',
      ],
      Third: [
        'lee',
         'mustaq',
         'vaas',
        'shane',
      ],
      Four: [
       'bumrah',
         'starc',
         'jadeja',
        'shami',
      ],
    };  


Export state 
export interface State {  
    headersList: Array<any>  
}
```

Main component class

```
export  class MyComp extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        headersList: headers, 
    };
```

Comment: You're assigning an object to an array.

Comment: @ritaj : can you give me some example .

Comment: headers is an object, while headersList is an array. you can't assign object to an array.

Comment: You can try to keep headerList as JSONArray, i.e array of json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.state = { 
    headersList: [headers], 
};
```

Will fix the problem

Comment: @JohnKenThat's good. You should probably change one of the types so they fit together a bit better. Which means either setting headersList to just one object of headers (this is probably the best way) or separate out the headers into an actual array. I can show you how to do these if you wish :)